# enable PMI Submodules with wsadmin

Tags: python, wsadmin

I'm stuck with my script. I am trying to set PMI submodules (such as f.ex JVM>GC) through a python script.
I am able to set the PMI Modules themself, but not their submodules. I already read that some of the submodules can only be changed with JVM profiling enabled, which I've already done.

I do have the problem of listing the submodules.
For listing the modules, I have used the following:

```
 #------------------------------------------------#
 # retrieve ids                                   #
 #  > Server                                      #
 #    > PMIService                                #
 #      > PMIModules                              #
 #------------------------------------------------#
 serverID = AdminConfig.getid("/Server:" + server + "/")
 pmiID = AdminConfig.list("PMIService", serverID)
 ...
 if level == "custom":
    pmim = AdminConfig.list('PMIModule', serverID)
    pmiList = AdminConfig.showAttribute(pmim,'pmimodules')[1:-1].split(" ")
    for modules in pmiList:
        modName = AdminConfig.showAttribute(modules,'moduleName') 
    
        if modName == "jvmRuntimeModule":
            AdminConfig.modify(modules, [ ["enable", "2,1,5,4,3" ] ])
```

With this code, I am able to set PMI for all the modules I want.

Currently I am trying this, but the result is always false:

```
if modName == "jvmRuntimeModule>GC":
            AdminConfig.modify(modules, [ ["enable", "11,12,13" ] ])
```

modName will never be jvmRuntimeModule>GC because it's a submodule...
Does anyone know if there is a possibility to list the submoules as well ?

Thanks a lot for your help,

Jérôme